# Use Subquery on Where IN with Multiple addSelect

Tags: symfony, query-builder

I have create a subquery and a query with querybuilder and i need to use the subquery  with where in, but my subquery use multiple select and i don't know how to handle that.

My subquery with multiple select :

```
        $qbLastHour = $this->createQueryBuilder('cc');
        $qbLastHour
            ->select('aa.id')
            ->addSelect('MAX(aa.createdAt) as mdate')
            ->addSelect('DATE_FORMAT(aa.createdAt, \'%d-%m-%Y\') as ddate')
            ->innerJoin('cc.analytics', 'aa')
            ->groupBy('cc.id')
            ->addGroupBy('ddate')
            ->orderBy('aa.createdAt', 'DESC');
```

My query :

```
        $expr = $qb->expr();
        $qb->select('a.id')
            ->addSelect('COALESCE(SUM(a.viewCount),0) as viewCount')
            ->addSelect('DATE_FORMAT(a.createdAt, \'%d-%m-%Y\') as date');
        $qb->innerJoin('c.analytics', 'a')
            ->andWhere($expr->in('a.id', $qbLastHour->getDQL()))
            ->addGroupBy('date')
            ->orderBy('a.createdAt', 'DESC');
```

I have the error :

Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_FROM, got ','",

I have that error beaucoup i use multiple select on my subquery.
If someone can help me. Thank you

Comment: maybe ... remove the multiple selects from your subquery? ... unless you need it afterwards, calling `->select('aa.id')` on it  *might* be enough

Comment: Yes i need it for GroupBy ddate.
I tried to use HIDDEN but it doesn't work :(
I need to use $qbLastHour->getQuery()->getResult() to work :(

Answer (score 0):

blatantly simple, you could have also just repeated the query though ... but this should work as well ... just capture what you got so far and keep expanding afterwards (you maybe have to fix what comes before and after the getDQL ;o)

```
    $qbLastHour = $this->createQueryBuilder('cc');
    $qbLastHour
        ->select('aa.id')
        ->innerJoin('cc.analytics', 'aa')
        ->groupBy('cc.id')
        ->orderBy('aa.createdAt', 'DESC');
    $dqlForLater = $qbLastHour->getDQL();
    $qbLastHour->addSelect('MAX(aa.createdAt) as mdate')
        ->addSelect('DATE_FORMAT(aa.createdAt, \'%d-%m-%Y\') as ddate')
        ->addGroupBy('ddate');

    $expr = $qb->expr();
    $qb->select('a.id')
        ->addSelect('COALESCE(SUM(a.viewCount),0) as viewCount')
        ->addSelect('DATE_FORMAT(a.createdAt, \'%d-%m-%Y\') as date');
    $qb->innerJoin('c.analytics', 'a')
        ->andWhere('a.id IN (:query)')
        ->setParameter('query', $dqlForLater)
        ->addGroupBy('date')
        ->orderBy('a.createdAt', 'DESC');
```

Alternatively, just put the first part into a function, and  the extension in another, when you need it with the added grouping, call both, and use the first to use in your main query (instead of `$dqlForLater`).